# if文でループを停止、再開させるには

Tags: arduino, processing

Arduinoとprocessing間のシリアル通信を利用した作品を作っています。
Arduinoに接続した2つのタクトスイッチから得たスイッチのON/OFFのデータをProcessingに送っています。2つのタクトスイッチをそれぞれ停止用、再開用として使いたいです。
Processing側では画像を20枚読み込み、それを表示させています。

やりたいこととしては、Processing側の画像の読み込みを、Arduinoから送られてきたスイッチの値によって停止・再開することです。
以下のコードでは、停止用スイッチを押すとsensors = 1 が送られ、if文の中のnoLoop()により画像の読み込みは停止します。しかし、もう片方の再開用スイッチを押した時に送られる値sensors = 2 で再開することができません。
mousePressed()の中のloop()によって、マウスをクリックすれば再開は可能ですが、今回はArduinoからの値を使って再開させたいです。

回答よろしくお願いいたします。

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

int numFrames = 20;
int  sensors; //センサーの値を格納

PImage[] images = new PImage[numFrames];

void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(1280, 800);
  frameRate(40);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  //images.resize(1280,800);
  for (int i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    images[i] = loadImage("animation-"+nf(i, 3)+".png");
    images[i].resize(1280, 800);
  }

  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/cu.usbmodem143401", 9600);
}

void draw() {

  int frame = frameCount % numFrames;
  if (sensors == 0) {

    image(images[frame], width/2, height/2);
  } 
  if (sensors == 1) {
    //image(images[frame], width/2, height/2);
    noLoop();
  } 
  if (sensors == 2) {
    image(images[frame], width/2, height/2);
  }
}

void serialEvent(Serial p) {
  sensors = p.read();
  println(sensors);
}

void mousePressed() {
  loop();
}
```

Comment: マウスクリックの場合と同様に `if (sensors == 2) { loop(); }` とするのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そちらもif(sensors==3){noLoop();}で完全にdrawが止まってしまってif(sensors==2){loop();}まで行かないんです。

Comment: こちらで解決とのこと。[if文でループを停止、再開させるには](https://teratail.com/questions/224972)

Answer (score 1):

そもそもですが、なぜnoLoop()させる必要があるのでしょうか？。noLoop()はdraw()関数の呼び出しを停止する命令ですので、当然ですがそれ以降はloop()命令を発行するまで、draw()関数の中に記述された処理は動作しなくなります。
int frame = frameCount % numFrames;
と書かれた処理でフレーム数を20で割った余りを求めていますが、表示画像を一時停止（frame変数の更新を停止）したいのであれば、sensors == 0かsensors == 2の時だけ、frameCount % numFramesの処理をすれば良いのではないでしょうか？
つまり

```
void draw() {

  int frame;
  if (sensors == 0) {
    frame = frameCount % numFrames;
    image(images[frame], width/2, height/2);
  } 
  if (sensors == 2) {
    frame = frameCount % numFrames;
    image(images[frame], width/2, height/2);
  }
}
```

です。勘違いしていたら申し訳ないです。